# What free alternatives to Photoshop are there for making Android Icons?

Tags: android, icons, adobe-photoshop

The Android sdk has a section [Using the Android Icon Templates Pack](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html#templatespack) that says in part ...

The icon templates are provided in the Adobe Photoshop file format (.psd), which preserves the layers and design treatments we used when creating the standard icons for the Android platform. You can load the template files into any compatible image-editing program...

Photoshop is pretty expensive just for making a couple of Android icons.

What alternatives are available to open the .psd files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [Paint.NET](http://www.getpaint.net/index.html) (with [this plugin](http://psdplugin.codeplex.com/)) or the [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/).

Comment: And my tip, since your templates are already PSD files, would be to download the trial version of Photoshop from Adobe, open your files, save the layers out individually (or just save a layered TIFF), then you can do whatever you like with them in Paint.NET or GIMP.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/), the GNU image editor. Or if you simply don't want to pay for the full version of Photoshop you could always [rent it for a month](http://www.adobe.com/products/creativesuite/cssubscription.html).

Also worth checking out is the [Android Asset Studio](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

try [The Gimp](http://www.gimp.org). It has a plugin which can read .psd files. Though CMYK psds may give it trouble, as Gimp has no native CMYK mode.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's a list](http://www.file.com/extension/psd):

> Mac OS
>
> - Adobe Illustrator CS5
> - Adobe InDesign CS5
> - Roxio Toast 11
> - Apple Preview
> - Corel Painter 12
> - GIMP
>
> Windows
>
> - Adobe Illustrator CS5
> - Adobe InDesign CS5
> - Apple QuickTime Player
> - CorelDRAW Graphics Suite X5
> - Corel PaintShop Pro X4
> - Corel Painter 12
> - ACDSee Photo Manager 14
> - ACD Systems Canvas 12
> - MAGIX Xara Designer Pro
> - GIMP
> - DXTBmp
>
> Linux
>
> - GIMP

Answer (score 1):

For GIMP there is a [script](http://izvornikod.com/Blog/tabid/82/EntryId/5/GIMP-script-for-creating-Android-icons-at-once.aspx) for creating all icons for different sreen resolutions at once.